# content-type causes chrome to call function twice

Tags: php, google-chrome, pdf, content-type

Most peculiar problem with following code. It returns a pdf report to the browser.

```
function cart_aspdf() {
    trace('cart_aspdf_in');
    $file = 'order_WS000250.pdf';
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $file . '"');
    $file =  APPPATH.'pdfcache/'.$file;
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    trace('cart_aspdf_readfile');
    @readfile($file);
    trace('cart_aspdf_out');
}
```

The trace output in opera,firefox,ie,safari is as you would expect:

> 1. cart_aspdf_in
> 2. cart_aspdf_readfile
> 3. cart_aspdf_out

BUT the trace for chrome shows the following which seems to indicate that the function is being called at least twice if not three times. Why should this be so?

> 1. cart_aspdf_in
> 2. cart_aspdf_readfile
> 3. cart_aspdf_out
> 4. cart_aspdf_in
> 5. cart_aspdf_readfile
> 6. cart_aspdf_in
> 7. cart_aspdf_readfile
> 8. cart_aspdf_out

The problem does not occur if I omit the content-type line but then chrome shows the raw pdf data which is no use

Comment: Chrome can't recall your function, but chrome can reload the page where the function was called. To prevent your code calls the function more times add exit; at the end.

Comment: Hi Andrey, exit after readfile (I think thats what you mean) made no difference. the function is called via an anchor on the page ie <a href="..cart_aspdf"> etc. Alternatively I can just enter the url and each time i press rfresh, i can see the trace. It works perfectly in all browsers except chrome. I want to stop it because at the moment, the code just outputs a finished pdf but the intention was that the pdf would be generated on the fly which is a non-runner if chrome is going to lead to it being generated twice. Bill

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline;');
```

For whatever reason, when the content-disposition is inline it calls the page twice.

This was giving me problems trying to use the referrer because the second call does not pass referrer data.

using

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;');
```

only runs once, but will not display inside the browsers PDF viewer. It will instead download the file.

I think this needs to be posted on chrome's bugtracker. This is quite annoying and for streaming files a bandwidth waste.